# Sumproduct Arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

i have this array:

```
money(v, q)

[50, 2]
[20, 2]
[10, 2]
.
.
.
n
```

i need to do this

```
(money[0].v * money[0].q) + (money[1].v * money[1].q) + (money[n].v * money[n].q)
```

can you help me please?

I tried

```
 for (i = 0; i > money.length; i++)
 {
 (money[i].v * money[i].q) + (money[i++].v * money[i++].q)
 }
```

but mathematically it's incorrect and i don't know how to make it right

Thanks a lot

Comment: It would be easier to understand if you could add `array`, `v` and `q`. What is the output that you're getting and what is the expected output?

Answer (score 1):

I don't full understand how your array is set up. So, I am making an assumption that is is an array of arrays like this `[ [50,2], [20,2], [10,2] ]`.

If that assumption is correct, then you could use the `Array.prototype.reduce()` method.

More info here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce

```js
const arrayOfArrays = [
  [50, 2],
  [20, 2],
  [10, 2]
];
const reduced = arrayOfArrays.reduce((a, c) => a + (c[0] * c[1]), 0);
console.log(`Total: ${reduced}`);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let result = 0
for (i = 0; i < money.length; i++){
 result += money[i].v * money[i].q
 }
```

You start by declaring a variable outside of your for loop to hold the result.
Then each time you go through the loop, you add the product of v and q for the current i value to the result variable.